# Bootstrap, can you disable display flex?

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

I have the following css thats breaking my layouts:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.row {
    display: flex;
}
```

Can I disable the display flex rule? Can anyone explain why this happens?

Update:

Currently using [boostrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.5"
Cant find the line in my sass files, probably not much help but it appears here in my compiled css:

```
strong {
  font-weight: 600; }

.wrapper {
 padding: 50px 20px; }

 // row class here

**@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row {
  display: flex; } }**

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .column {
width: 50%; }
.column:first-child {
margin-right: 20px; } }

.modal__button {
 margin-right: 5px; }

@media (max-width: 500px) {
 .modal-dialog {
width: 100%;
margin: 10px auto; } }

.week-navigation {
  float: right; }

 .week-navigation__next-button {
  float: right; }
```

Comment: Read this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You didn't show the HTML, but I suspect you were missing a `<div class="col-12">` (or similar `col-X`) inside of the div.row. (I was getting confused by headings and paragraphs behaving as `flex` instead of `block`, and that was all there was to it.)

Answer (score 10):

CSS display property has several possible values. One of them, and the most recent, is flex. A HTML element with flex will automatically apply default properties to its children elements. You can check the following url to understand how flex works https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ 
So, if you don't want to use it, just override it, by using

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.row {
    display: block;
}
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, whats confusing me is its just started to appear and I cant think why.

Comment: Hey, this answer will not solve your problem. You will have several more components of the bootstrap framework that are dependent on display: flex; still active.

You will have to disable flexbox within the bootstrap framework for an across the board solution to your problem. I provided the answer below, if you need more elaboration, I will be happy to assist you through pm.

Comment: Actually it will solve. Because if your container doesn't have the flex property, all the elements inside with CSS properties related with flex, won't take any effect.

Answer (score 3):

Can you tell me a little more about where this following block of CSS is located? What version of bootstrap are you running as well? It may be something as simple as changing a boolean from true to false and then recompiling the SCSS that bootstrap 4 (assuming that is the version you are using) provides.

If you are using an older version of bootstrap, then you have a library, or CSS you wrote yourself that is overwriting. I am leaning that your issue is being caused by the prior assumption.

---

If you have SASS installed on your computer already and are familiar with it as well, then this is easy. Locate the _variables.scss file that is included with bootstrap and inside of it you will find the following property:

```
$enable-flex: true !default;
```

You want to change this to:

```
$enable-flex: false !default;
```

After you have done this, recompile bootstraps the SCSS and you will then have disabled flex throughout the entire bootstrap framework.

Comment: Thanks im using boostrap-sass, "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.5"

Comment: I was able to grab the project from GitHub and I was unable to find any scss, or css elements with the property of display: flex; It was version 3.3.5

Can you do a project search for flex in your IDE and put a file mask on all scss and css files (*.scss, *css)

Comment: ah ok, must be coming in from somewhere else then, I knew it was strange in Bootstrap 3

Comment: I concur with @Dmidify, I downloaded via Bower (v3.3.6) this morning for a demo and there's no flex support in there. Somehow you've got the "_grid.scss" mixin or similar from Bootstrap 4...

Comment: Has this $enable-flex param gone from the latest version of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4:

```
div.row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    ...
}

div.row div.col {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    ...
}
```